# Ruby convert comma separated values to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to print each values in a line separately. I want the TCP, ports and CIDR to be printed as array values.

```
sg_rules="TCP,80,80,0.0.0.0/0
TCP,8080,8080,0.0.0.0/0"


sg_rules.each_line  do |rule|
    rule.split(',')
    print rule[0]
end
```

But I'm getting the following output. I expected `TCP` as the result.

`Output:`

```
$ruby main.rb
TT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call 'split' that returns an array but does not actually store the result in `rule` variable...

Try this:

```
sg_rules.each_line  do |rule|
  print rule.split(',').first
end
```